# Receipt printer has how many paper left?

Tags: printer

Background, I have a client request, to know how many papers are lefts, for example, let's say 0 to 100% so they can view the percentage on their mobile devices.

To achieve this, is there any existing printer that has this function? or any alternative solutions for the typical thermal printers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assuming that you are wanting know how much paper is left on a receipt printer.  Since you can get rolls of different lengths, it would make it very difficult.  And the receipts are of different lengths.  So, it cant  tell you **number of receipts to go**

Comment: This is why they have pink stripes down the last bit of the roll. Simple visual confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printers do not have a sensor to check how much paper is left and are not designed to make such modification easier.

You can try to estimate average length of a receipt, and when replacing the roll - provide its length to an app. Than you count every print, subtracting said average from new roll.

That could be done purely in software (app on mobile, short script on computer using a printer). But it would be work extensive to calibrate and would also require input from user at every replacement. Of course, it would never be precise, I'd say that if you achieve accuracy to dozens of percent and "last 20%", that would be great success.

As for precise solution you could use a sensor to check roll diameter which would give you amount of paper left. But that would be (way too) expensive, require precise sensor (possibly optical for this range of diameters) and also require carefulness at every paper replacement and probably also when working.